# Escape dot in Helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

In `values.yaml` I have:

```
key1:
  key2.yaml:
    key3:
    - name
      value
    - name
      value
```

Inside a template, how can I get to `key3`? `{{ .Values.key1.key2.yaml.key3 }}`  does not work because `key2.yaml` in this context corresponds to

```
key1:
  key2:
    yaml:
      key3:
      ...
```

Escaping the `.` with `\` results in:

```
$ helm template .
Error: parse error at (...): bad character U+005C '\'
```

Comment: interesting. however, this violates [naming rule](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/values/) though yaml is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core Go [`text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) language includes an `index` function, which can look up an arbitrary item in a map by string key (or an array by numeric key).  The key can be any valid template expression, including a string literal.  `index` can take multiple parameters to do nested lookups.

So, you can use `index` to do that specific lookup like:

```
{{ index .Values "key1" "key2.yaml" "key3" }}
```

If that mapping is supposed to be an arbitrary list of files and their contents, the template `range` function will return the keys and values, and you don't necessarily need the lookups.

```
{{- range $filename, $contents := .Values.key1 }}
$filename: |-
{{ $contents | toYaml | indent 2 }}
{{ end -}}
```